# Populating ListView Items from SQL Lite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

I need help again.
I have a listView in an activity and i need to populate its items from a database..
Any suggestions or tutorials for the problem?

Thanks in advance.
Waiting for your replies...

Comment: Did you try anything, before asking this question ?

Comment: are you talking about a local db or a db on a server?

Comment: Why dont you google before asking a question ?
See this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaOsl2TtMHs (First page first result from Google)

Comment: and the database is local...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some links where you get some useful example for Create ListView From SQLite Database in Android Development

[Link1](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/listview-data-sqlitedatabase),
[Link2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/learn-how-to-create-listview-from-sqlite-database-in-android-development/),
[Link3](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

for a local databse on the phone itself, its handy to use a [sqlite-database](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

for an external Database, you need a WebService (for example: php) to access the MySQL-database. one example is [here](http://innovationonandroid.blogspot.de/2012/10/android-php-mysql.html)

this will take some time to figure it out. i would recommend to try a local-database with sqlite for starters